# Use paths from Force Layout as ClipPath

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm generating voronoi paths based on some points in forced layout. I'd like to randomly assign these paths 1 of 10 classes and then wrap some of these classes with a clipPath that I can then apply to another element.

Is it possible to wrap svg tags around elements using d3 as opposed to appending?

Or is it even possible to use multiple paths generated by d3 in a clipPath?

Thank you for your help,

```
w = $(window).width();
    h = $(window).height();

    function ranNum(){
        return Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
    }


    $('#grid').css('height', h);

    var vertices = d3.range(50).map(function(d) { return {x: d.x, y: d.y}; });
    //console.log(vertices);


    links = [];
    voronoiVertices = [];
    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(vertices)
        .size([w, h])
        .linkDistance(60)
        .charge(-900)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);


    //path gradient
    var defs = svg.append('defs')
    var radialGradient = defs.append('radialGradient')
        .attr('id', 'pathGrad')
        .attr('cx', '50%')
        .attr('cy', '50%')
        .attr('r', '50%')
        .attr('fx', '50%')
        .attr('fy', '50%');

    var stop1 = radialGradient.append('stop')
        .attr('offset', '.2')
        .attr('stop-color', '#a8a8a8');

    var stop2 = radialGradient.append('stop')
        .attr('offset', '1')
        .attr('stop-color', '#0000000');

    //path dropShadow
    var filterShadow = defs.append('filter')
        .attr('id', 'pathShadow')
        .attr('height', '130%');

    var gCir = svg.append('g')
        .attr("class", "gCircle");

    var gPath = svg.append('g')
        .attr("class", "gPath");

    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle");   
    var path = gPath.selectAll("path")
            .data(d3.geom.voronoi(vertices))
                .enter().append("path")
            .attr("fill", "url(#pathGrad)");

            //wraps path with random class after generation
    $('path').each(function(){$(this).attr('class', 'path-' + Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1))});

    var clip = defs.append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("id", "clip-rect")
            .attr("x", "0")
            .attr("y", "0")
            .attr("width", '900px')
            .attr("height", '900px');

    var gClip = svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');
/*
    var clip = gClip.append("svg:image")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("xlink:href", "clip.jpg")
        .attr("x", "0px")
        .attr("y", "0px")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h); 
*/
    var selectPath = d3.selectAll('.path-10');      
    console.log(selectPath);    


    function tick() {
        voronoiVertices = vertices.map(function(t){return [t.x, t.y]})  
        path = path.data(d3.geom.voronoi(voronoiVertices))
            path.enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", function(t) { return "M" + t.join("L") + "Z"; });
        path.attr("fill", "url(#pathGrad)")
            .attr("d", function(t) { return "M" + t.join("L") + "Z"; });        

        circle = circle.data(vertices)
        circle.enter().append("circle")
            .call(force.drag)
            .attr("r", 0)
            .attr('class', function(d) { return d.index; })
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
            .transition().duration(5000).attr("r", 5);

            circle.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a strange mix of jQuery and D3 in this. Try to do the things in D3 when you work with it. For example I'd rather do this:

```
.attr("class", function(d){return 'path-'+Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1))});
```

than this:

```
$('path').each(function(){$(this).attr('class', 'path-' + Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1))});
```

d3 has an [exotic but smart way of doing things](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218), it's better to learn this update pattern well before doing something serious.

And here is the working code:

```
w = 1200;
h = 500;

function ranNum(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
}


var vertices = d3.range(50).map(function(d) { return {x: d.x, y: d.y}; });
//console.log(vertices);


links = [];
voronoiVertices = [];
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(vertices)
    .size([w, h])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-900)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);


//path gradient
var defs = svg.append('defs')
var radialGradient = defs.append('radialGradient')
    .attr('id', 'pathGrad')
    .attr('cx', '50%')
    .attr('cy', '50%')
    .attr('r', '50%')
    .attr('fx', '50%')
    .attr('fy', '50%');

var stop1 = radialGradient.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '.2')
    .attr('stop-color', '#a8a8a8');

var stop2 = radialGradient.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '1')
    .attr('stop-color', '#0000000');

//path dropShadow
var filterShadow = defs.append('filter')
    .attr('id', 'pathShadow')
    .attr('height', '130%');

var gCir = svg.append('g')
    .attr("class", "gCircle");

var gPath = svg.append('g')
    .attr("class", "gPath");

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle");   
var path = gPath.selectAll("path")
        .data(d3.geom.voronoi(vertices))
            .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", "url(#pathGrad)");

        //wraps path with random class after generation
//$('path').each(function(){$(this).attr('class', 'path-' + Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1))});

var clip = defs.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("id", "clip-rect")
        .attr("x", "0")
        .attr("y", "0")
        .attr("width", '900px')
        .attr("height", '900px');

var gClip = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');


function tick() {
    voronoiVertices = vertices.map(function(t){return [t.x, t.y]})  
    path = path.data(d3.geom.voronoi(voronoiVertices))
        path.enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", function(t) { return "M" + t.join("L") + "Z"; });
    path.attr("fill", "url(#pathGrad)")
        .attr("d", function(t) { return "M" + t.join("L") + "Z"; });        

    circle = circle.data(vertices)
    circle.enter().append("circle")
        .call(force.drag)
        .attr("r", 0)
        .attr('class', function(d) { return d.index; })
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .transition().duration(5000).attr("r", 5);

        circle.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```

Good luck!